# Ansible Hostname as variable in ansible_user

Tags: ansible

Need help with ansible. In our company we use following method to ssh to a server.
If IP of server is 172.16.1.8 , Username would be "empname~id~serverIP" e.g. john~1234~172.16.1.8 . So following ssh command is used -

```
> ssh john~1234~172.16.1.8@172.16.1.8 -i key.pem
```

Basically username has the hostname as a variable.

Now our inventory has just IPs with group web.

```
> cat inventory.txt
[web]
172.16.1.8
172.16.x.y
172.16.y.z
```

My playbook yml has ansible user as following.

```
> cat uptime.yml
- hosts: web
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_port: xxxx
    ansible_user: john~1234~{{inventory_hostname}}
  tasks:
  - name: Run uptime command
    shell: uptime
```

However, when I use following ansible-playbook command, it gives error for incorrect username.

```
> ansible-playbook -v uptime.yml -i inventory.txt --private-key=key.pem
```

Please help me find correct ansible_user in playbook which has hostname as a variable inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `ansible_user` in *group_vars/web.yml*

*group_vars/web.yml*:

```
---
ansible_ssh_port: xxxx
ansible_user: "john~1234~{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Comment: I tried following, group var , but it did not help, also debug is not working, cannot see what was output of ansible_user variable -                                                                    ---
  vars:
    ansible_user: john~1234~{{ inventory_hostname }}

  -debug: var=ansible_user

Comment: Remove `vars:`section from your playbook

Answer (score 0):

Using a group var helped -

---

ansible_ssh_port: xxxx
ansible_user: "john~1234~{{ inventory_hostname }}"